# Converting range of times in any format to hours and minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conversion, range

In Excel, I'm looking for a simple way to convert a 24-hour format time range (in various formats) to hours and minutes.

For example, I might have different hour/minute range formats:

9-12  // result 03:00

9-12:45  // result 03:45

09:30-15:40  // result 06:10

9:20-13   // result 03:40

I can assume that

- all hours will be in the same day - i.e. between midnight and 11:59pm.
- there will be no spaces in the range string
- there will always be a hyphen separating the hour/minute ranges
- minutes will always be padded with a 0 on the left (e.g. 9:05 but never 9:5)

I can convert a properly formatted 24-hour range (e.g. 09:30-15:45) using this formula:

=TEXT(MOD(TEXT(RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND("-",C2)),"hh:mm")-TEXT(LEFT(C2,FIND("-",C2)-1),"hh:mm"),1),"hh:mm")

I can convert single integer hours (e.g. 9) to the hh:mm format:

=TEXT(A1/24,"hh:mm") // result 09:00

I can convert unpadded h:mm format (e.g. 9:30) to padded hh:mm format:

=TEXT(B3,"hh:mm")  // result 09:30

However, I'm not seeing a single function to convert everything to hh:mm, so I can apply my formula. And I'd prefer not to use a bunch of IF statements in the formula to check for colons, but if necessary, I will.

Answer (score 1):

With a version of Excel with the `LET()` function (2021 or 365)  the following formula works for a string of the type specified in the OP and placed in cell `A1`. The result cell containing the formula needs formatting with an `hh:mm`.

```
=LET(
    s, A1,
    d, FIND("-", s),
    time2, RIGHT(
        s,
        LEN(s) - d
    ),
    time1, LEFT(s, d - 1),
    (
        VALUE(time2) /
            IFERROR(
                --(
                    FIND(
                        ":",
                        time2
                    ) > 0
                ),
                24
            )
    ) -
        (
            VALUE(time1) /
                IFERROR(
                    --(
                        FIND(
                            ":",
                            time1
                        ) > 0
                    ),
                    24
                )
        )
)
```

The bits before and after the time separator `-` in the string expression are found, much in the same way as in the OP, using the usual string functions and assigned as variables *time1* and *time2* in the `LET()` and converted to numerical values via the `VALUE()` function. Where a *time* string does not contain a colon, its numerical value is divided by 24, otherwise it is divided by 1.

The divisors in the `LET()` are given by

`IFERROR(--(FIND(":",time2)>0),24)` for string *time2*  and

`IFERROR(--(FIND(":",time1)>0),24)` for string *time1*

So no `IF`'s but a slightly cheating `IFERROR` instead.

The availability of the `LET()` function just allows repetitive bits of Excel to be expressed in a shorthand way. This means that the string containing the two times is expressed as *s* and is defined as being cell `A1`, with the position of the dividing separator in this string being at character position *d* within the string.

Instead of repeating use the phrase `FIND("-",A1)` when finding the parts of the string before and after the separator (the "time strings"), as in

`RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1))` and
`LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1)-1)`

within the OP, it is simply replaced by *d* in the `LET` version.

The expression involving the conversion of a time string to its numeric time value divided by 1 or 24 involves using the time string in two functions: `VALUE` and `FIND` (this time looking for a ":"). This approach allows the phrase

`VALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1))) / IFERROR(--(FIND(":",RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1)))>0),24)`

to be shortened in the `LET()` function to

`VALUE(time2) / IFERROR(--(FIND(":",time2)>0),24)`

Without use of the `LET` function the formula could be written as:

`=(VALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1)))/IFERROR(--(FIND(":",RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1)))>0),24))-(VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))/IFERROR(--(FIND(":",LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))>0),24))`

Comment: This works.  I'm using Excel 2019, so had to use the non-LET version.  Then just surrounded the formula with TEXT(formula,"hh:mm") for the final result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TEXTSPLIT` function.

With Microsoft 365, enter the following formula in some cell.
The results for all will SPILL down.

```
=BYROW(
    $A$1:$A$4,
    LAMBDA(arr,
        LET(
            s, TEXTSPLIT(arr, "-"),
            sB, TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(s, 1), ":"),
            sBh, INDEX(sB, 1),
            sBm, IFERROR(INDEX(sB, 2), 0),
            sE, TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(s, 2), ":"),
            sEh, INDEX(sE, 1),
            sEm, IFERROR(INDEX(sE, 2), 0),
            B, TIME(sBh, sBm, 0),
            E, TIME(sEh, sEm, 0),
            E - B
        )
    )
)
```

- `$A$1:$A$4` is the range to be processed.

  - This can be replaced by any single column range reference
- `s`: split the string on the hyphen
- `sB`: split the first part of `s` on the colon
- `sBh`: the hour part of the beginning time
- `sBm`: the minute part of the beginning time

  - `IFERROR` in case there are no minutes
- Similar process for `sE`, `sEh`, and `sEm`
- `B` and `E`: create actual time values

***Note***: The results will need to be formatted as `[hh:mm]` else they will display only the fraction of a day

[image]